# Restore AJAX handling for ASP.NET Core to previous functionality

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In previous MVC5 and below, you could make an ajax call that unwrapped the parameters properly:

JS:

```
$.post('/controller/endpoint',{intparam: 1, strparam: 'hello'})
```

CS:

```
public ActionResult endpoint(int intparam, string strparam){}
```

In the new aspnetcore, it has changed:

CS:

```
public CustomClassWrapper{ 
    public int intparam {get;set;}
    public string stringparam {get;set;}
}
public ActionResult endpoint([FromBody]CustomClassWrapper item){}
```

To sum it up, in the new framework, you need to write a wrapper class and can only pass one [FromBody] parameter to the method. Previously, the params would be unwrapped by variable name correctly.

So, i'm trying to re-implement this functionality in an aspnetcore middleware component. I'm having difficulty in how to accomplish calling the controller method properly with the parameters.

My current cut-down code:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (IsAjaxRequest(context.Request))
            {
                try
                {
                    string bodyContent = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body).ReadToEnd();
                    var parameters = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(bodyContent);
                    ///What to do here?
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception("AJAX method not found ", ex);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await _next(context);
            }
        }
```

I'm really just not sure about what to do after deserializing the parameters.  I have the URL for the endpoint and also the params correctly. Just need to know how to call the method and return the result as JSON. Should i be using Reflection to get the controller method? Or is there a better way using MVC?

Comment: Why do you need the middleware? Is your ultimate call to call your .NET Core method "endpoint" with Ajax?

Comment: Yes, but i need to unwrap the parameters passed.

Comment: @Steve, Do you want to call `public ActionResult endpoint(int intparam, string strparam)` post method using AJAX call? and you don't want to use model. is that your requirement?

Comment: Yeah pretty much.

Comment: I am able to call ActionResult using AJAX and without using model. not required middleware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try implement custom IModelBinder.

```
public class BodyFieldModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.EnableRewind(); // required to read request body multiple times
        var inputStream = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Body;
        if (inputStream.Position != 0L)
            inputStream.Position = 0;
        var bodyValue = new StreamReader(inputStream, Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();
        var jsonObject = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(bodyValue);
        if (jsonObject.TryGetValue(bindingContext.FieldName, out var jToken))
        {
            var jsonSerializer = JsonSerializer.Create();
            var result = jToken.ToObject(bindingContext.ModelType, jsonSerializer);
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(result);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

*Be careful, the code above lacks error handling and etc.*

And use it like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Endpoint([ModelBinder(typeof(BodyFieldModelBinder))] int intparam)
```

Also you could implement custom attribute to reduce complexity of declaration:

```
public class BodyFieldAttribute : ModelBinderAttribute
{
    public BodyFieldAttribute()
        : base(typeof(BodyFieldModelBinder))
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but thank you! This works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

it's very simple thing i don't know why it not working at your end

**JS**

```
$.post('actionMethodURl', { FirstName: '1', LastName: 'hello' }).done(Successfunction);
```

**CS**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult endpoint(string FirstName,string LastName)
{
  object Message = string.Empty;
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
     Message = "Pass";
   }
   else
   {
   Message = ModelState.Errors();
   }
   return Json(Message);
}
```

[image: MyJSCode]
[image: MyActionMetho]

Comment: Did you do this in ASP.NET Core? This looks like old MVC.

Comment: i did this in Core 2.0